# React Material Table - data is not filtered correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-design, material-table

I am using Material Table in my React project. All is rendered just fine but filtering and searching is not OK. I have created sample code here:

> https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-franklin-hkxet?file=/src/Table.jsx

Problem is that whatever I type in Search Bar or in Custom Column Filter it is giving 0 results. Even a single letter is enough to make returned results 0.

What could cause the problem? Is it from the way I render data in every column? If yes, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're using nested properties in your row data, just like how you customize your displayed text in the `render` property, you need to override `customFilterAndSearch` too if you want the filter to function properly:

```js
{
  title: "League",
  field: "League",
  render: (rowData) => rowData.league.name,
  customFilterAndSearch: (term, rowData) =>
    rowData.league.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1
},
```

Reference: [Custom Filtering Algorithm Example](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/filtering)

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67092391/react-material-table-data-is-not-filtered-correctly]